# Why observer is not notified when observable object runs as new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have computational class that implements Runnable interface (for the readability I've simplified it):

```
public class ColorReduction extends Observable implements Runnable {

    public ColorReduction(Layer inputLayer, Layer outputLayer) {
        this.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        addObserver(new ActionObserver());
    }

    public void run(){

        notifyObservers(EAction.COLOR_REDUCTION_START);
        setChanged();

        // some computation stuff.....

        notifyObservers(EAction.COLOR_REDUCTION_FINISH);
        setChanged();

    }

}
```

and in a controller I run this class as a new thread:

```
ColorReduction cr = new ColorReduction(model.getInputLayer(), model.getOutputLayer());

            Thread t = new Thread(cr);
            t.start();
```

**Question:** an observer (`ActionObserver`) is notified only at the end of color reduction phase (`COLOR_REDUCTION_FINISH`) and not at the beginning of this phase (`COLOR_REDUCTION_START`).

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call setChanged() first:

```
this.setChanged();
this.notifyObservers(EAction.YOUR_ENUM_VALUE);
```